# "Live" data capable alternative for Google Earth KML

Tags: gps, google-earth

I'm currently using Google Earth + KML Files to visualize Aircraft Flightpaths in 3d, it works perfect and also looks fine, but the big disadvantage is, that there seems to be no way to feed "live" data to Google Earth and draw the Flightpaths in Realtime.
Is there an alternative that is capable to display live data without manually reloading a file or anything like this? Satellite Picture surface would be an absolute MUST.
Maybe someone out there knows a proper solution for my project.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The KML NetworkLink tag provides several ways to automatically update/reload a KML file, which will let you provide "live" data.  You can either make the NetworkLink update the KML every time the user stops moving the map (with a setable delay), or on a timer (eg: every 10 seconds).  Look at the KML Reference and developer tutorials for more info.